# Unable to change file encoding to utf-8

Tags: linux, files, unicode, character-encoding, ascii

I modified a `UTF-8` encoded xml file using vi editor and saved it.

I'm on Redhat Linux 7.9

I checked the file encoding after the changes and found it to be `us-ascii`

```
file --mime-encoding tmpfiles/08/config/jdbc/jdbc.xml
tmpfiles/08/config/jdbc/jdbc.xml: us-ascii
```

I decided to change the encoding back to `UTF-8` using the below command:

```
iconv -f us-ascii -t UTF-8 tmpfiles/08/config/jdbc/jdbc.xml >tmpfiles/08/config/jdbc/jdbc.xmlenc

echo $?
0
```

However, the encoding for the new file `jdbc.xmlenc` did not change to `UTF-8` and remained unchanged. See the output below:

```
file --mime-encoding tmpfiles/08/config/jdbc/jdbc.xmlenc
tmpfiles/08/config/jdbc/jdbc.xmlenc: us-ascii
```

Can you please suggest how can i change the file encoding to `UTF-8`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's going to be UTF-8 only if your document contains UTF-8 characters.

US-ASCII is a subset of UTF-8 thus any US-ASCII text is also a valid UTF-8 text. There's no need to convert anything.

Comment: Is there a way i can get UTF-8 printed as output?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Please clarify.

Comment: Is there any command that can print the superset i.e `UTF-8` as output?

Comment: Would be great if you let us know what you're trying to achieve. Pure ASCII will be ASCII/UTF-8 no matter how you print it. Add any UTF-8 symbol and it will stop being ASCII and will become UTF-8.